# Alter a Deep Part of Views Query

Tags: views, 8

Views has a minor bug that causes this particular part of a query to be "AND" when it should be "OR." With this being Drupal 8, figuring out how to alter that value is difficult. For one, it's nested inside a \Drupal\Core\Database\Query\Condition. And the part I need to change is the '#conjuction'.

Does anyone have any advice on how I would target that? Oviously just working with the xdebug path does not work.

```
$query->where[2]['conditions'][0]['field']->conditions['#conjunction'] = 'OR';
```

[image: xdebug view of query]

Comment: If this is a bug of Views, you could start by finding the related issue with a possible patch available or open a new one https://www.drupal.org/node/add/project-issue/drupal. Regarding your situation, did you already check that your filter fields are configured properly, i.e. use an OR conjunction operator?

Comment: I'm of course struggling to find the particular issue I was reading earlier so that I can link to it. It's a known issue, though obscure. No patch. But there isn't a solution yet. So i was thinking, ok, that's fine, I'll try to alter the query. That turned out harder than I thought since what I need to change is so nested. I thought I might try posting here in case someone could help me isolate how to tackle this particular part I need to alter.

Comment: Okay, still need to know how to reproduce this. And do let us know which issue describes the problem. Could you post a picture of your current view configuration, especially the filters part?